# How to change ownership of a remote file tree

Tags: nfs, ownership

I have a tree of files on a remote server, and I want to obtain ownership of them. The tree is mounted at **/Musique**.   I tried `chown -R paul /Musique` but I got an error message "Invalid argument" for every file in the tree.

I think if I could mount the tree with the **no_root_squash** option, that would fix the problem. Currently, I mount the tree like this:

```
mount -t nfs 192.168.0.21:/volume1/Musique /Musique
```

That mounts the tree correctly, but I can't change  the ownership of the files in it. I can't figure out where to put **no_root+squash**.  I think it should be an option on the **mount** command, but I just haven't been able to get the syntax right.

The remote server is a Synology network attached storage unit. I've created a user **paul** there, but I haven't figured out how to get the numerical user IDs into correspondence.

Comment: Is there actually a user named `paul` on the remote server? Does it have the same numerical UID as `paul` on your local system?

Comment: ...  in any case, `no_root_squash` isn't something you can set as a client-side mount option, it would need to be specified in the server-side `exports` file

Answer (score 1):

Mounting with `-t nfs` you are using NFSv3. This has almost no concept of the  "identity mapping" added in NFSv4, so your NFSv3 Server needs to have a user with the same UID as your system's user named `paul`. It would be a good idea to name the remote user `paul` as well.

You are probably getting "Invalid argument" because the NFSv3 Server does not have any user with `paul`'s UID, so you're trying to change ownership to a user which the NFSv3 Server does not know about.

To find `paul`'s UID on your computer, use `id -u paul`. For example:

```
$ id -u paul
1000
```

Make a user on the NFSv3 Server named `paul` with the same UID as you got above (eg: 1000).

If the NFSv3 Server is a NAS with a web interface, then use that.

If the NFSv3 Server is a Linux system, create a group and a user like so. Change the UID from `1000` if needed:

```
groupadd -g 1000 paul
useradd paul -u 1000 -g 1000 -M
```

Now you should be able to change ownership of the NFSv3 files to `paul`.